# Processmaker sending variables using Soap routeCase getting a Not Found error

Tags: php, processmaker, processmaker-api

Sending Variables To another case in Processmaker using __SoapCall routeCase method and getting the error Not Found. Yet in working in the __SoapCall'login'.

Below is my PHP Code in processmaker

```
$client = new soapclient(
$wsdlUrl,
[
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    'verifyhost' => false
]
);

$client->__setLocation($endpoint);

$params2 = [
[
    'sessionId' => $sessionId,
    'caseId' => $caseId,
    'delIndex' => $delIndex
]
];
try{
    //dd($client,$params);
    $result2 = $client->__SoapCall('routeCase', $params2);                          

}catch (Exception $e){
    throw new Exception("Soap request failed! Response: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

The error I am getting is ** Soap request failed! Response: Not Found**

What issue causes the Not Found error?

Comment: That's not JavaScript, looks like PHP

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by an issue in the environment and not an issue with the code. The above code works perfectly for continuing another process in process maker from another process